# Calculate $\sum ^ {6} _ {k = 0} Re (z_k) $

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $ z_k \left (k = 0,1,2,..,6 \right) $ be the roots of: $ (z + 1) ^ 7 + (z) ^ 7 = 0 $. We can say that:$$ \sum ^ {6} _ {k = 0} Re (z_k) $$is equal to?

attemp: By Vieta, the sum of the roots of this polynomial is $-\frac{7}{2}$ (the polynomial is $2z^7 + 7z^6 + A(z)$, where $\deg A \leq 5$ is a polynomial, so $\sum \Re(z_k) = \Re(\sum z_k) = \Re\left(-\frac{7}{2}\right) = \boxed{-\frac{7}{2}}$.

Does this equation have 7 solutions? Am I correct?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: @user Does the equation really have more solutions? This is important?

Comment: It is a polynomial of $7$-th degree. Therefore it has exactly 7 complex roots (counted with multiplicity if required).